# Linux - Compile program from source and create a package to install on identical servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, package

I'm setting up Amazon EC2 instances for video conversions using FFMPEG. Since it's EC2 (I'm using RightScale to manage them) I have to make script files which will fully configure the instance after boot. The system is ubuntu.

I have to compile FFMPEG from sources and several other tools from source, and this takes ages (20mins), which will be too long when a new instance will be needed.

So, is there any way to compile FFMPEG and somehow make an own package (like the ones used by aptitude) so I can just download and unpack it on a fresh instance? The whole system will be always exactly the same, so it doesn't have to be very flexible.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your compiled tools in an S3 bucket and download to a fresh instance. However, if you're using ubuntu, its usually a matter of 'apt-get'ing the required software.

Comment: I found out that it's possible to make custom .deb packages with checkinstall and then just install them on the instance. It works ok since I know I have all needed dependecies installed in the system.